# Over the course of history, did Linux and Windows NT kernel design learn from each other?

Tags: operating-systems, os-kernel

Linux Kernel in its primitive form was first written in 1991; Windows NT kernel (differ from Win9x Kernel which was based on DOS) purportedly began development in 1990. both being a monolithic kernel, they must've faced similar OS design problems.

and I think OS design can't entirely be "original" in several senses:

1. good design will always influence later designs.
2. new features are getting added or replacing some older ones as time goes by.

So, over the course of three decades, what are some notable design/mechanism in each kernel that were heavily influenced by the other? And by "design", it could be a specific mechanism (e.g. pool tag in NT or refcount in linux) or an entire subsystem (e.g. VFS in linux or CSRSS in NT).

*(P.S. these two kernels were chosen because they are the most popular ones in terms of market share, it very well could be that some design were influenced by other kernels but that's a different question.)*

Comment: In the 1990s and early 2000s, the champion of innovation in OS design was SunOS/Solaris. Everybody copied BSD's networking. GUIs came from Xerox in the 1980s with others including Next and Apple leading the way later. Linux and Windows weren't the innovation leaders in the 1990s.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about the history of technology, not about the history of science. It might be on-topic on [retrocomputing.se] but I don't know if 1990s versions of contemporary OSes are considered on-topic there (the history of OSes that have disappeared or mostly disappeared is on-topic).

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' thats a good direction, however I don't know how to find the most suitable location for this question, if moderators have this kind of power, please move the entire question to appropriate site, some insightful comment about this on stackoverflow was already lost during first repost.